# Regarding sdk and environment in mobilefirst studio

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

In the process of creating an Hybrid app while adding other environmenent i mean adding apple and android thus it requires the necessary sdk to be preinstalled in eclipse help pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MobileFirst Studio generates for you the native project for each environment.

- iOS: an Xcode project is generated. You then need to open it in Xcode, which requires a Mac.
- Windows/Windows Phone: a Visual Studio project is generated. You then need to open it in Visual Studio, which requires a PC running Windows 8 or above
- Android: for the native project to be generated, you need to:

  - either install the Android ADT plug-in for Eclipse
  - or setup Android Studio and open the project there

Much like your previous question, the answer to this is in the Getting Started training materials. Please read them: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/setting-up-your-development-environment/

Comment: thank you , yep i m getting into the tutorial but lots of doubt poking my head as i am very new to this pls kindly cope up sir :) :)